# BASIC programming language getting variable

Tags: basic

On MSX BASIC 2.1, I get this error when compiling my basic code.

```
10 Input "Your name", U$
run
Syntax Error
OK
```

Why is this syntax incorrect?

Comment: That might depend on which version of BASIC you are using.

Comment: Version 2.1 is what I'm using

Comment: Version 2.1 of which BASIC product?

Comment: It might actually matter.

Comment: Based on a quick Google search, it looks like the comma might need to be a semicolon (http://www.atarimagazines.com/creative/v10n2/204_Simple_screen_graphics_wi.php ).

Comment: That did the trick! Yay!

Comment: Traditionally in BASIC, the semicolon `;` has been used to separate the text of the input prompt from the input variable, whereas commas usually are used to separate multiple variables. The original Dartmouth BASIC allowed multiple variables from the beginning, like this:<br>

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that you may need INPUT in upper case and the semicolon.  Try the following.

```
10 INPUT "Your name"; U$
```

Comment: A semicolon `;` was the delimiter between the prompt string and the variable name for this command in the original Dartmouth BASIC (1964) and the earliest versions of line numbered BASIC.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to use a semicolon instead of a comma (See the use of the `INPUT` command on [this page](http://www.atarimagazines.com/creative/v10n2/204_Simple_screen_graphics_wi.php) for example)